# How to add multiple values based on a date range displayed per day

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, date-range

I have the following two tables. The first is a set of date ranges with three values assigned to each date range.

```
Start Date   End Date   A Hours    B Hours   C Hours
1/1/2014     1/10/2014  5          10        0
1/2/2014     1/5/2014   10         0         5
1/5/2014     1/15/2014  5          5         5
1/10/2014    1/30/2014  0          0         15
```

The second table is a list of dates with the same three values for each date.

```
Date       A Hours    B Hours   C Hours
1/1/2014            
1/2/2014            
1/3/2014            
1/4/2014            
1/5/2014
```

I am looking to find the total number of A Hours, B Hours and C hours per day based on the date range in table one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using `SUMIFS()`

H2 formula `=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"<="&G2,B:B,">="&G2)`

I2 formula `=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,"<="&G2,B:B,">="&G2)`

J2 formula `=SUMIFS(E:E,A:A,"<="&G2,B:B,">="&G2)`

Drag formulas down

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this one in `B9` and drag it down and across (see image below):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A9>=$A$2:$A$5)*($A9<=$B$2:$B$5)*(C$2:C$5))
```

[image]